# Modify the array to minimize the difference

Tags: arrays, algorithm

You are given an array `A` of `n` values and a value `k`. You have to either increase or decrease every element in `A`  by `k` and must do it only once for every element. The goal is to minimize the difference between the largest and the smallest elements in the resulting array `A` (after modification) and output this difference.

For example, `A=[1,7]`, `k=4`, we need to modify `A` as `[5,3]`, then the difference is `2`, which is the minimum difference we can achieve.

Can anyone help me on how to solve this question?

Comment: Well what exactly are you looking for? An algorithm to solve the problem? A proof of it hardness? I would quess that this can be done via dynamic programming,

Comment: And in what language?

Comment: This looks like homework, where is your code?

Comment: @Codor I want an algorithm for solving this question. Hardness prove is also very welcome.

Comment: What is the expected time complexity?

Comment: @luba any language is fine, just need to algorithm and logic.

Comment: @VedangMehta I don't know. Maybe linear or quadratic.

Comment: @VedangMehta sure, how to do it in O(n^2), i think there is very much cases to consider... thanks very much.

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of calculating the average? Do `A[i]+k` if it's below the averge, and `A[i]-k` if it's above. With the only exception that when `max(A) - min(A) < k` you want to do all `A[i]+k`. For instance `k=4, A=[1,2]` you want `[5,6]` not `[5,-2]`. Did I miss a special case?

Comment: @Halcyon I think the case when A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and k=5 will not work for the average method. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @lebesgue For `A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7], k=5` The average is `4` so you get `A*=[6,7,8,-1,0,1,2]` which gives `9`. I guess the exception should be if `max(A)-min(A) < max(A*)-min(A*)`, so you get `6`. I think this is `O(2N)` because you only need two loops.

Comment: Checkout my DP solution. My previous greedy hypothesis was incorrect. @lebesgue

Comment: @Halcyon If the correctness of this logic could be proved?

Comment: @Halcyon I think it is not correct either. How about for the case A=[1,14,16,29] and k=10?

Comment: @lebesgue There is a similarity between this problem and **Histogram equalisation**. If we consider a[i] as the absolute frequnceny of the number i, the process of **Histogram equalisation** transforms the input histogram to an histogram that looks approximatly uniform, so for each i, j in {0, 1, ..., (n-1)}: d(a[i], a[j]) <= epsilon, with epsilon > 0(epsilon is very small lim epsilon nears 0). The point is how could we use this fact to only go by +k or -k

Comment: @AyoubFalah did you submit a solution? I cannot see it now...

Comment: @lebesgue I submitted my answer. The algorithm behind the implementation has an order of `n*log(n)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to think about it (imagine a sorted array, `x`'s are `a[i] + k` and `y`'s are `a[i] - k`)

```
x
  x
      x
           x
y              
  y             x[i](min?)
      y                   x
           y                  x[n-1]
                y[i](min?)     
                          y   
                              y
```

If you choose `y[i]` as the minimum, your choice for maximum would be:

```
max( y[0], x[i + 1] )
```

And if you choose `x[i]` as the minimum...oh you can't since any `a[j] ± k, j > i` must be smaller in this sorted arrangement.

If you choose `x[n-1]` as the minimum, your choice for maximum would be the largest of all `min(x[j],y[j]) where both x[j] and y[j] are greater than or equal to x[n-1] (or just x[j] if y[j] < x[n-1])`.

If you choose `y[0]` as the minimum, your choice for maximum would be `max(x[j])`, provided that all `x[j]` are greater than or equal to `y[0]`.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about your idea? Thanks

Comment: @lebesgue just think about the implications of assigning `y_i` as minimum - the matching max has to come from either the greatest `y` on the left, which is the closest possibility in this ordered arrangement, except if there is a greater `x` to the right of `y_i`. Oh, but i'm missing something, let's see if i can fix the formula

Comment: @lebesgue only if the array is sorted, otherwise you have to add sorting complexity.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Thanks for your view.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm with an order of `O(n*log(n))`:

```
public class MinDiff 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int A[] = {1,7};
        int k = 4;
        System.out.println("Input a:=" + Arrays.toString(A) + ", k:=" + k);
        find(A, k);
        System.out.println("Output a´:=" + Arrays.toString(A));
    }

    private static void find(int a[], int k) 
    {       
        Arrays.sort(a);

        int n = a.length;
        if (k > a[n - 1] - a[0])
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                a[i] += k;
            return;
        }

        a[0] = a[0] + k;
        a[n - 1] = a[n - 1] - k;

        int max = Math.max(a[0], a[n - 1]);
        int min = Math.min(a[0], a[n - 1]);

        for (int index = 1; index < n - 1; index++) 
        {
            if (a[index] < min)
                a[index] += k;
            else if (a[index] > max)
                a[index] -= k;
            else if ((a[index] - min) > (max - a[index]))
                a[index] -= k;
            else
                a[index] += k;

            max = Math.max(a[index], max);
            min = Math.min(a[index], min);
        }
    }
}
```

**Input:** a:=[1, 7], k:=4

**Output:** a´:=[5, 3]

Comment: Where does `k` go?

Comment: @Halcyon Ohh, sorry. I forget it. I will try to rework the suggested algorithm

Comment: @lebesgue space and time?

Comment: @AyoubFalah if your code works correctly for the case A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and k=5?

Comment: @lebesgue Yes you are right. The algorithm is wrong. It´s now to late(in Germany) and I must wake up early because of work. I will extend it later. Thank you for your observation

Answer (score 0):

My recursive dynamic programming solution in C++.The time complexity is *O(N3)*-

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>
    #include <map>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <limits>

    using namespace std;

    vector <int> v;
    map < pair <int, pair <int,int> >, int > mp;

    int k, n;

    int solve(int index, int minimum, int maximum)
    {
            if(index == n)
                    return maximum - minimum;
            pair <int, pair <int,int> > p = pair <int, pair <int,int> > (index, pair <int,int> (minimum, maximum));
            if(mp.find(p) != mp.end())
                    return mp[p];
            int x = v[index] - k, y = v[index] + k;
            return mp[p] = min(solve(index + 1, min(x, minimum), max(x, maximum)), solve(index + 1, min(y, minimum), max(y, maximum)));
    }

    int main()
    {
            int p = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
            int q = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
            cin >> k >> n;
            int x;
            for(int i = 0;i < n;i++)
            {
                    cin >> x;
                    v.push_back(x);
            }
            cout << solve(0, p, q) << endl;
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you provide me with the logic behind?

Comment: Since it is DP approach, it evaluates every single possibility. If the values are already evaluated, we'll retrieve them from the map.

Comment: How could you make sure the algorithm is O(n^3) instead of exponential? @VedangMehta

Comment: The memoization will bring down the complexity to O(n^3). There are 3 parameters for the function and each of them can have N, 2N and 2N unique values. So the complexity will be O(N * 2N * 2N) which is same as O(N^3).

Comment: Yeah, good, good. Thanks for your solution. Do you think there are faster methods in terms of complexity, like O(n^2)?

Comment: I believe that there should be a greedy solution for this problem. I just haven't gotten around to conceptualize it.